# Error running ImageMagick from R: Invalid parameter

Tags: r, shell, animation, imagemagick, system

I am trying to make a GIF-animation in R. I have an array of matrices which i wish to convert into a GIF animation. My strategy is inspired from this example:

http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/animate-gif-images-in-r-imagemagick/

where the following code produces 11 PNG-Pictures with the "png"-function in R. Next it calls for the external ImageMagick-program "convert" to compile the GIF animation.

```
dir.create("examples")
setwd("examples")

# Animated countdown from 10 to "GO!".
png(file="example%02d.png", width=200, height=200)
for (i in c(10:1, "G0!")){
plot.new()
text(.5, .5, i, cex = 6)
}
dev.off()

# convert the .png files to one .gif file using ImageMagick. 
system("convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")
#shell("convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")
```

The problem is that R doesn't seem to finde the exe-file "convert" which is a part of ImageMagick and installed on the C-drive (C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16). In the comments to the website [i am linking to earlier](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/animate-gif-images-in-r-imagemagick/), it is suggested for Windows users to use "shell" instead of "system" to run external programs but none of the two work. The error message is

```
Invalid parameter - 80
Warning message:
running command 'convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif' had status 4
```

I've tried to change the Windows PATH enviroment variable in the systems properties, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132332/help-with-savegif-function-in-libraryanimation/6135579#6135579), but the PATH-variable was allready corectlly defined on my system. I also tried specifying the whole string of the convert.exe file, but also without luck...

How can i get ImageMagick to run through R?

Specs:
Windows 7 Servicepack 1,
R 3.0.0

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The error message you quote is not indicating that R is not finding `convert`... What error message do you get when you use the full path? One possibility is that you have another `convert` program in your `PATH`. In case you added the directory at the end of the `PATH` environment variable, try putting it at the beginning instead.

Comment: What does `system("where convert", intern = TRUE)` give you?

Comment: The very first filepath in the `convert` variable is the ImageMagick filepath, just checked again. When i run the code `system("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")` apparently nothing happens. 
When i run ´shell("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")´ i get the error message: 
`'C:/Program' was not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file.` and then a whole series of R-errors.

Comment: The code you suggest give the following result: 
`> system("where convert", intern = TRUE)
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16\\convert.exe"
[2] "C:\\Windows\\System32\\convert.exe"` 
Thank you very much for you help... it's greatly apprieciated.

Comment: Try `system("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif", intern = TRUE)`

Comment: While "apparently nothing happens", was the file `example_1.gif` created?

Comment: No the GIF was not created. I have type it the windows searchbar to check it didn't appear somwhere else, but no result.

Comment: I get the error: `> system("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif", intern = TRUE) Error in system("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif",  : 
  'C:/Program' not found`

Comment: maybe `system('"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16\\convert.exe" -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif', intern = TRUE)` then.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! Do you have any idea what went wrong originaly? What does `intern=TRUE` mean?

Comment: I'm still not sure. Does `system('convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif', intern = TRUE)` work? Also try `convert.exe`. `intern = TRUE` is just so it captures the output, so you have more info to work with whether it works or not.

Comment: Both yield the same error: `> system('convert.exe -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif', intern = TRUE)
[1] "Invalid parameter - 80"
attr(,"status")
[1] 4
Warning message:
running command 'convert.exe -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif' had status 4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, there are several convert.exe commands, all of which are in the PATH. So you must specify the path to the right convert.exe executable. In my case, I had it in the LyX folder (however, you will find it in the ImageMagick installation too).
Be careful with the quotes, the backslashes and the spacing if you are pasting. E.g. from within R:

```
system('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\imagemagick\\convert.exe" -delay 20 -loop 0 files_*.png animation.gif')
```

Comment: Actually since this answer the command in magick changed to avoid clash with sytem32. Just use: system (magick convert -delay 40 -loop 0 *.png example_1.gif") and do not forget to specify your path in cd if your target are in a folder that is not your working directory 
system ("cd YOUR PATH")

Answer (score 3):

I'm a windows 10 user, after defining the working directory I got it working in R using

```
shell("convert -set delay 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test.gif")
```

within cmd each command means the following

convert = open convert function from ImageMagick

-set delay x = set the delay time between each frame to x  (1000 = 1 second)

-loop 0 = loop forever, if set to 1 it will go through the images once

*.[image type]= and file of .[image type]

[name of output gif].gif = save new .gif as

I got it working first within command prompt by navigating to the directory and running the line

```
convert -set delay 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_cmd_test.gif
```

Before this I was using 
    -delay = 80 
rather than 
    -set delay 80
in cmd and got error:
convert: invalid argument for option '-delay': = @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1277.

In R using the system() command with the correct "-set delay x" I was getting error:

```
> system("convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_3.gif")
Invalid Parameter - delay
Warning message:
running command 'convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_3.gif' had status 4
```

other errors in shell()

```
> shell("convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test11.gif")
convert: unable to open image '80': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test11.gif' had status 1 
2: In shell("convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test11.gif") :
  'convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test11.gif' execution failed with error code 1
```

I ran it in R with shell() after and it seems to work fine

```
shell("convert -set delay = 80 -loop 0 *.jpg example_shell_test.gif")
```

Do have a look at this thread also

[ImageMagick - Issue with Windows and convert function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163849/imagemagick-issue-with-windows-and-convert-function)

Answer (score 0):

I know someone else already found the solution to your problem but there is an easier way to solve it without having to include the entire pathway in system(). Simply set`ani.options(convert = 'pathway/convert.exe')`
after loading the animation package.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting all of these fixes as well as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166098/error-in-savegif-command-in-animation-package/29168709#29168709) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132332/cannot-find-convert-using-savegif-function-in-animation-package) to no success, I used alternative software to make the conversion, several of which are described [here](http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Convert_an_image_sequence_to_a_movie). I am a Windows user and found the simple instructions contained in that site for [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/) quickly accomplished this task.