# Using R to convert png files to animation

Tags: r, animation, png, animated-gif

I have a number of png files and now like to covert these files into an animation using R. I did the following thus for 
    Install ImageMagick for Windows ( which is located C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16)

```
library(animation)
setwd("C:/Users/j/Desktop/CAN/New folder")
# reading my png files
bm.files = sprintf("min%i.png", 1:20)
head(bm.files)
[1] "min1.png" "min2.png" "min3.png" "min4.png" "min5.png" "min6.png"
# 
ani.options(convert = 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\\convert.exe')
# try to convert to gif
im.convert(files = bm.files, output = "bm-animation3.gif")
```

After running the above I got the following errors
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @     error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: no images defined`bm-animation3.gif' @   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212

I looked at solutions to my issue  on [error in saveGIF command in animation package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166098/error-in-savegif-command-in-animation-package/29168709#29168709) and several others places but not any closer to a solution. Any guidance to fix  would be most helpful

Comment: Dare I ask that your files are not actually in the folder you're setting your working directory to?  You can confirm this by using the `list.files()` function and verifying the PNG files are there after issuing the `setwd()` call. You might want to just try using a wildcard in your `im.convert()` call if you're absolutely positive the PNG files are in the current working directory.

Comment: Try the command `identify -list format | FINDSTR /i PNG` to see if you have `rw`, i.e. Read and Write support for PNG.

Comment: Forrest, my files are in my directory.

Comment: Mark, i am not certain what are asking me to do in R. ( i am still learning)

Comment: I meant for you to type the command I gave in a Windows Command Prompt (`Start->Programs->Accessories->Command Prompt`) and hit Enter. If you are inside R, you can do `system("identify -list format")` to see what is listed beside `PNG` - you want `rw` for the ability to read and write `PNG` files.