# ImageMagick - Issue with Windows and convert function

Tags: windows, imagemagick

I'm trying to use imagemagick to create a simple .gif file from a few png files, using the general approach outlined here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/animated-plots-with-r/

However, I'm on a Windows 10 machine, and I think that's causing problems with the convert function as generally described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19679

Can someone please explain how I can either change imagemagick or Windows so that it works?

Specifically the command I'm giving and the error that occurs is shown below:

```
convert *.png new.gif
```

The error:

```
Invalid Parameter - the.gif
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `convert` is a command, not a function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably installed ImageMagick 7.X on your machine. This version no longer includes `convert.exe` and the error that you are receiving is from the convert command of Windows. You can use `magick.exe` instead or select `Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)` during the installation to install `convert.exe` on your machine..

Comment: I thought convert was going to be a alias or whatever it is called for magick @dlemstra so it would still work.

Comment: Thank you to both of you.   The answer that @dlemstra indicates worked.  Specifically, I installed the legacy utilities, and then the convert function worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that `convert` is also a windows command ("converts a FAT partition to NTFS") hence the erroneous parameter (you're actually calling the "FAT2NTFS" utility from windows, which do not know the Image magick's `convert` parameters)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `convert.exe <args>`, use `magick.exe convert <args>`.

Comment: Imagick is a php API for Imagemagick; how is imagick.exe going to work in this case?

Comment: The name `imagick` [has been proposed](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/bugs/IMv7_Recommendations.txt) however.

Answer (score 0):

With Version: ImageMagick 7.0.3-4 Q8 x64 2016-10-10 on my Windows 10, adding 'magick' in front of 'convert' gets rid of the 'invalid parameter' error. For example, 

    `magick convert foo.jpg -quality 60 low_foo.jpg`

If preferring to define the steps in a file: save the following file as convert.sh:

    `SRC="$1" 
    LOW=60 
    magick convert $SRC.jpg -quality $LOW low_$SRC.jpg 
    magick convert $SRC.jpg -quality $LOW low_$SRC.webp 
    magick convert $SRC.jpg -quality $LOW -resize 50% "$SRC"_"$LOW"q_50pc.jpg
    magick convert $SRC.jpg -quality $LOW -resize 50% "$SRC"_"$LOW"q_50pc.webp`

and running `sh convert.sh foo` at a bash command prompt processes foo.jpg in four different ways. It bears to mention that after the installment, 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q8' appears first on the list at the System/Advanced System Setting/System Variable/Path.