# Error while converting .pdf file to .ppm in R

Tags: r, pdf, imagemagick, ocr, pdftoppm

I'm trying to apply OCR on a pdf to extract the text for which I'm following [this](https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/11333467) post ,
for which I need to first convert pdf file to ppm format since we cannot apply OCR directly on a pdf file. But the first step itself is not happening
So how do I convert pdf to ppm in order to do OCR on a pdf file.
This is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315958/error-while-doing-ocr-on-pdf-in-r?noredirect=1#comment79601345_46315958) of mine where I get an error on first step itself.
Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to extract the contents of a pdf in R, there are many other ways.

Comment: The pdf doesn't contain the plain text but it is OCR'd, that's the reason I'm not able to extract text from this OCR'd pdf